# Persistent notification with buttons in Nativescript

Tags: notifications, nativescript, interactive, persistent

I want to do a notification that persists as long as I want it on the notification area, and I want to add buttons in it to control actions in my app when it is not visible. Something like this:

[Persistent interactive notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvt3X.jpg)

How can I do that in Nativescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [nativescript-local-notifications](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-local-notifications) plugin.

```
tns plugin add nativescript-local-notifications
```

- `ongoing` - flag enables you persistent notification
- `actions` - let you add buttons

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have the persistent notification with buttons now. Now I want to make the buttons do something when I tap them. How do I do that? I'm looking at the docs and haven't found the way. For example, I want a `console.log()` when tapping an action button

Comment: Ok, I found it. There's an event called `addOnMessageReceivedCallback` that pass the notification object. That object contains the `response` property which shows the ID of the action button pressed. Thanks man! God bless you.